# Flip through all the instances of all the applications running - mac

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

Got my first Mac couple of days ago and I may be missing something.

Usually need to I open couple of instances of the same application: couple of IDE's for different projects, couple of Chrome browsers with different profiles.. etc.

When I try to jump from one application to the other using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> I see only the applications and not the instances. Meaning only one icon of Chrome(!!) only one icon for IDE(!!).

I know you can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and get to the application and then <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to iterate between the instance but that's pretty bad compromise for a pretty basic task.

Is there a way to have it the same as Windows - Where I can flip through all the instances of all the applications running on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

There's an application called [Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) that you might be interested in. Also this question was once asked at the [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79221/cmd-tab-showing-different-windows-from-a-single-app)